# Using the base form of to be to form a passive sentence

Tags: verbs

The different forms of the verb **to be** include: **be**, am.is, are, was,were, being and been.
I understand that a passive construction is made up of the **to be** form + the past participle of a transitive verb.

However, I am wondering if the actual base **verb be** can be used to form this construction. If not, then why not?

Also, I know that the base form be is used as an auxiliary verb after modals, but can it ever occur as a main verb on its own?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can form passive verbs with "be".

> In order to be eaten, the mushrooms should be cooked completely.

This (rather artificial) sentence has two infinitive, passive phrases.  There is a "to" infinitive "to be eaten" and a bare infinitive "be cooked" (following a modal "should").  An infinitive "to be" can't be the main verb of a sentence. Every sentence should have a finite verb (with some exceptions in exclamations).

The passive voice is relatively rare, and so infinitive phrases in the passive voice are even rarer, but there is nothing odd about this kind of construction.

It isn't possible to use "be" as the main verb in a passive construction, because it doesn't have an object.  It is incorrect to say "a teacher should be been"

Comment: @Jamies Thank you for your answer. What I.'m struggling with is a sentence I posted earlier ( We see the internet be used in many places) A student I volunteer with wrote this and I couldn't explain to him why "be used" doesn't sound right . I suggested "being used".  I thought it might be something to do a rule related to using "be" in a passive structure.

Comment: That seems simple enough, the verb "see" wants a gerund, not an infinitive for that meaning.  Gerunds are "...ing" so in a passive form "being used".   Its just a gerund/infinitive question  (there are lots of those)